# Search in subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, subdocument

Hello I want to get all the contacts with syncFlag true in contact object.

[I tried this solution but only returns only one sub document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array)

and I also tried this solution it returns all the documents either they are matched or not

[How to find document and single subdocument matching given criterias in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586901/how-to-find-document-and-single-subdocument-matching-given-criterias-in-mongodb/25587818)

Here is the sample document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ce7d6c7387d533bfa2d45c"),
    "ITBCompanyId" : 2608,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-06T12:19:35.972Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-06T08:25:16.325Z"),
    "name" : "This is test",
    "identifier" : "THDNOM2",
    "addressLine1" : "Valencia Lahore",
    "syncFlag" : true,
    "orgId" : "1",
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "whois" : [ 
        {
            "test" : "noman"
        }
    ],
    "configuration" : [ 
        {
            "test" : "noman"
        }
    ],
    "contact" : [ 
        {
            "firstName" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb04811f005420b7ed54a"),
            "syncFlag" : false,
            "communicationItems" : [],
            "customFields" : []
        }, 
        {
            "firstName" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb04811f005420b7ed54b"),
            "syncFlag" : false,
            "communicationItems" : [],
            "customFields" : []
        }, 
        {
            "firstName" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb44b5f8b534bc312aacd"),
            "syncFlag" : true,
            "communicationItems" : [],
            "customFields" : []
        }, 
        {
            "firstName" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb457f141fd4c1c98a748"),
            "syncFlag" : true,
            "communicationItems" : [],
            "customFields" : []
        }
    ],
    "agreement" : [ 
        {
            "test" : "noman"
        }
    ],
    "companySite" : [ 
        {
            "test" : "noman"
        }
    ],
    "companyNote" : [ 
        {
            "test" : "noman"
        }
    ],
    "type" : {
        "name" : "Client"
    },
    "status" : {
        "name" : "Active"
    },
    "id" : "19493",
    "__v" : 0,
    "_info" : {
        "updatedBy" : "Omer",
        "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-09-06T11:52:07.000Z")
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
 ITBCompanyId: 1,
    contact: [{
               "firstName" : "Active",
                "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb04811f005420b7ed54b"),
                "syncFlag" : true,
                "communicationItems" : [],
                "customFields" : []

    }]
```

Comment: Add document that is the expected result.

Comment: @tarashypka I told in question I only want to found contact objects with syncFlag true

Comment: then your expected output should contain two objects as:        `{
            "firstName" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb44b5f8b534bc312aacd"),
            "syncFlag" : true,
            "communicationItems" : [],
            "customFields" : []
        }, 
        {
            "firstName" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb457f141fd4c1c98a748"),
            "syncFlag" : true,
            "communicationItems" : [],
            "customFields" : []
        }`

Comment: Do you want `"ITBCompanyId"`, `"updatedAt"` and other fields to be in the output for each document from the collection? Or you want only an array of unique contacts for all documents in the collection?

Comment: I only want array of contacts which have syncFlag true, and yes I want ITBCompanyId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You should get the document as required. Below I have used an aggregate query to format the mongodb response as required. For more information regarding mongodb aggregate, you can refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). I reffered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb) stack overflow post for forming this query.

```
db.companies.aggregate(
    { $match: {"contact.syncFlag": true }},
    { $unwind: '$contact'},
    { $match: {"contact.syncFlag": true }},
    { $group: { 
            _id: '$_id',  
            contact: {$push: '$contact'},
    }
});
```

If you want all the other fields included in the document. You can try this.

```
db.companies.aggregate(
    { $match: {"contact.syncFlag": true }},
    { $unwind: '$contact'},
    { $match: {"contact.syncFlag": true }},
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$_id', 
        ITBCompanyId: {$first: '$ITBCompanyId'}, 
        updatedAt: {$first: '$updatedAt'}, 
        createdAt: {$first: '$createdAt'}, 
        name: {$first: '$name'}, 
        identifier: {$first: '$identifier'}, 
        addressLine1: {$first: '$addressLine1'}, 
        syncFlag: {$first: '$syncFlag'}, 
        orgId: {$first: '$orgId'}, 
        deletedAt: {$first: '$deletedAt'}, 
        whois: {$first: '$whois'}, 
        configuration: {$first: '$configuration'}, 
        contact: {$push: '$contact'},
        agreement: {$first: '$agreement'},
        companySite: {$first: '$companySite'},
        companyNote: {$first: '$companyNote'},
        type: {$first: '$type'},
        status: {$first: '$status'},
        id: {$first: '$id'},
        _info: {$first: '$_info'},
    }
});
```

Comment: One solution is for limited fields and the other is for when all fields are included.

Comment: Don't copy paste the exact same query..change the collection name to the appropriate name of your collection, in my answer I have given the name of the collection as companies.

Comment: Sir for your kind information I know I have to change the collection name as per my collection name. But it did not work that's why I pasted it here. And I am asking you the question why the both solution did not work, and look what you are answering which is very obvious

Comment: {
 "result" : [
  {
   "_id" : ObjectId("57ce7d6c7387d533bfa2d45c"),
   "contact" : [
    {
     "firstName" : "Active",
     "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb44b5f8b534bc312aacd"),
     "syncFlag" : true,
     "communicationItems" : [ ],
     "customFields" : [ ]
    },
    {
     "firstName" : "Active",
     "_id" : ObjectId("57ceb457f141fd4c1c98a748"),
     "syncFlag" : true,
     "communicationItems" : [ ],
     "customFields" : [ ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "ok" : 1
}

Comment: The response I had obtained using the first query